# How can i allow a self made jar file the permission for reading and writing while autostart?

Tags: java, debian, read-write, autostart, init.d

first at all i want to say, i'm not a studied programmer.

I have written a server application and want to start these server automatically if i reboot a raspberry pi (operating System is debian).

My server application creates folders for security certificates when its starting about the command `File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "Security")`.

If i start my application as a jar file through a shell the application works fine. But if i start these application through the autostart the application starts but the folders won't be created. I think my application hasn't the permission to write on the system.

I´ve tried to put the jar file into a start/stop script in etc/init.d but the prolem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

**RPI INFO**
Solution to run you application with sudo permission:
1.Open terminal and type: *sudo nano /etc/rc.local*
2.Add line /path/to/your/application &
3.Ctrl+x, Y, Enter to save

Now your application have sudo permission, and you have right to crate any folder